# RXJS Subscribe to a Subject - Actions must be plain objects. Use custom middleware for async actions

Tags: redux, rxjs

I'm trying to subscribe to a subject. This is working as expected the first time  but throwing the above error the second time and I can't see where to fix it.

```
export function uploadSceneFile(action$, store) {
  return action$.ofType(CREATE_SCENE_SUCCESS)
    .mergeMap(({payload}) =>
      UploadSceneWithFile(payload)
        .map(res => {
          if (res.progress > 0){
              return { type: UPLOAD_SCENE_PROGRESS, scene: res }
          }
          else if(res.progress === -1){
              return { type: UPLOAD_SCENE_SUCCESS, scene: res }
          }
        })
    )
}
```

It's designed to listen for the scen being created, dispatch upload progress notifications and then dispatch the success message.

The error gets thrown straight away from this line the second time it runs

> onProgress: (val)=> subject$.next({...scene,progress:val}),

```
export function UploadSceneWithFile(scene){

  const subject$ = new Subject()

  scene.filename = scene.file.name
  scene.type = scene.file.type.match('image') ? 0 : 1

    FileToScenePreview(scene).then(res => {
    scene.thumbName = res.thumbName
  })

  const uploader = new S3Upload({
    getSignedUrl: getSignedUrl,
    uploadRequestHeaders: {'x-amz-acl': 'public-read'},
    contentType: scene.file.type,
    contentDisposition: 'auto',
    s3path: 'assets/',
    onError:()=>subject$.next('error'),
    onProgress: (val)=> subject$.next({...scene,progress:val}),
    onFinishS3Put: ()=> {
      subject$.next({...scene,progress:-1})
      subject$.complete()
    },
  })
  uploader.uploadFile(scene.file)

  return subject$.asObservable()
}
```

ERROR MESSAGE

```
   Subscriber.js:242 Uncaught Error: Actions must be plain objects. Use custom middleware for async actions.
    at Object.performAction (<anonymous>:1:40841)
    at liftAction (<anonymous>:1:34377)
    at dispatch (<anonymous>:1:38408)
    at createEpicMiddleware.js:59
    at createEpicMiddleware.js:59
    at SafeSubscriber.dispatch [as _next] (applyMiddleware.js:35)
    at SafeSubscriber../node_modules/rxjs/Subscriber.js.SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub (Subscriber.js:238)
    at SafeSubscriber../node_modules/rxjs/Subscriber.js.SafeSubscriber.next (Subscriber.js:185)
    at Subscriber../node_modules/rxjs/Subscriber.js.Subscriber._next (Subscriber.js:125)
    at Subscriber../node_modules/rxjs/Subscriber.js.Subscriber.next (Subscriber.js:89)
    at SwitchMapSubscriber../node_modules/rxjs/operators/switchMap.js.SwitchMapSubscriber.notifyNext (switchMap.js:126)
    at InnerSubscriber../node_modules/rxjs/InnerSubscriber.js.InnerSubscriber._next (InnerSubscriber.js:23)
    at InnerSubscriber../node_modules/rxjs/Subscriber.js.Subscriber.next (Subscriber.js:89)
    at MergeMapSubscriber../node_modules/rxjs/operators/mergeMap.js.MergeMapSubscriber.notifyNext (mergeMap.js:145)
    at InnerSubscriber../node_modules/rxjs/InnerSubscriber.js.InnerSubscriber._next (InnerSubscriber.js:23)
    at InnerSubscriber../node_modules/rxjs/Subscriber.js.Subscriber.next (Subscriber.js:89)
    at MergeMapSubscriber../node_modules/rxjs/operators/mergeMap.js.MergeMapSubscriber.notifyNext (mergeMap.js:145)
    at InnerSubscriber../node_modules/rxjs/InnerSubscriber.js.InnerSubscriber._next (InnerSubscriber.js:23)
    at InnerSubscriber../node_modules/rxjs/Subscriber.js.Subscriber.next (Subscriber.js:89)
    at MapSubscriber../node_modules/rxjs/operators/map.js.MapSubscriber._next (map.js:85)
    at MapSubscriber../node_modules/rxjs/Subscriber.js.Subscriber.next (Subscriber.js:89)
    at Subject../node_modules/rxjs/Subject.js.Subject.next (Subject.js:55)
    at S3Upload.onProgress (uploadSceneFile.js:27)
    at S3Upload.<anonymous> (s3upload.js:139)
```

Comment: You have an `if` and an `else if` in that inner `map`- in `uploadSceneFile` - so is it possible that it's returning `undefined`?

Comment: I love you. Seems to have worked.. put is as an answer and I'll mark it correct. (I added an undefined returned action and it seems to have made the error go away)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the inner `map` within your `uploadSceneFile`, you have an `if` statement followed by an `else if` statement, of if neither is `true`, the `map` will return `undefined` instead of an action.

```js
.map(res => {
  if (res.progress > 0){
    return { type: UPLOAD_SCENE_PROGRESS, scene: res }
  }
  else if(res.progress === -1){
    return { type: UPLOAD_SCENE_SUCCESS, scene: res }
  }
  // An action should be returned here!
})
```

Note that, when passed an `undefined` action, the [check that Redux performs](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux/blob/v4.0.0/src/utils/isPlainObject.js#L6) to determine whether or not an action is a plain object will effect the error you are seeing.